# Strange use of undeclared identifier in mmintrin.h clang error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, clang

I am trying to build my app for my device and am including the `libosmscout` library. Strangely, one of Apple's headers is giving me a load of errors:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/7.3.0/include/mmintrin.h:39:5: Use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_emms'; did you mean '__builtin_isless'?

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/7.3.0/include/mmintrin.h:39:25: Too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 0
```

[image]

I don't understand why is going wrong here. Where does the `mmintrin.h` file come from? Could I be missing an include somewhere? It appears to be a clang error.

Comment: mmintrin.h is responsible for MMX intrinsics. MMX is a kind of instruction set. Maybe it's related to your architecture. May changing it or CPU related settings help you. Give it a try!

Comment: Hmm, you mean Architecture settings?

Comment: Maybe. It could because of that or any conflict of used library with clang settings.

Comment: @Mehdihosseinzadeh Any hints on how I could figure this out?

Comment: @NicHubbard, did you solve your problem ? i am facing same issue.

Comment: @gstream79 It was a while ago, but it was a C++ library issue. Can't even remember what I did to fix it.

Comment: thanks for your reply. solved my self. it was a c++ library issue. you are right.

Comment: @gstream79 what was your library issue?

Comment: dang I am 3rd to ask "What did you do to fix it?"

Comment: @Qndel It was too long ago, I honestly don't remember. :(